# First Octant of the volume of $3N$-dimensional hypersphere

Tags: statistical-mechanics, volume

I am reading Pathria and Beale's Statistical Mechanics, 3rd ed. and came across this expression of calculating the first Octant of the $3N$-dimensional hypersphere at page 13:

[image: 1/8 of hypersphere]

The volume of the hypersphere is given in the curly bracket.
In 3D, the factor would be 1/8 but I couldn't figure out how the $(1/2)^{3N}$ factor arise. Why it is $1/2$ instead of $1/8$?

Comment: $N=1$ is 3D. ...

Comment: @G.Smith thanks, but how does this generalised to 3N dimension? I couldn't find an intuitive explanation of this factor.

Comment: The “quadrant” is the region where every coordinate is positive. Half of every coordinate line is positive.

Comment: I see it now and I will answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by G.Smith's comment above, my argument goes as follows:

Consider a $2D$ circle, to find a quarter of it we do"half of the half", i.e. $\frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$.

For $3D$ sphere, to find 1/8 of the sphere we again do "half of the half of the half", i.e. $\frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{8}$.

So the general trend goes like $\frac{1}{2}^N$, where N is the degree of freedom of the system. And in my question, $N=3N$,  hence $\frac{1}{2}^{3N}$.